# Specify Column With in R's gtsummary with tbl_cross?

Tags: r, gtsummary, flextable, quarto

I am creating a cross-tabulation table in R with the tbl_cross funtion using @daniel-d-sjoberg's gtsummary package.  I am trying to figure out how to specify the output column widths with gtsummary so I can modify the width of the first column in the table.  In addition, I want to take advantage of gtsummary's formatting options like bolding and breaking table captions over two lines (by specifying "  \n" in the modify_caption statement).  The problem is, I can't seem to break a caption over multiple lines AND specify a column width.  My starting point was to use the following code, which breaks the caption, correctly, onto two lines:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)

mytable <- iris %>% 
          mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
        tbl_cross(
          row =  Long.Petal,
          col = Species,
          percent = "cell"
        ) %>% 
         modify_caption("This is line 1  \n  This is lin 2")
```

This outputs the following table:

[image]

After reviewing the documentation, it looks like the only way I can find to modify the column widths is by converting the table to a flextable using gtsummary's as_flex_table and then specifying the column widths.  So, to do this, I modified the code above to change the width of the first column to 3 inches by adding two additional lines of code as indicated in the comments in the revised code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)

mytable <-   iris %>% 
      mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    tbl_cross(
      row =  Long.Petal,
      col = Species,
      percent = "cell"
    ) %>% 
  modify_caption("This is line 1  \n  This is lin 2") %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>%   #NEW CODE LINE 1
  width(., 1, 3)        #NEW CODE LINE 2

mytable
```

This code produces the output below, which has now incorrectly placed lines 1 and 2 of the table caption onto a single line.

[image]

Is there a way, preferably in gtsummary with tbl_cross or its options to specify the column widths  AND break a table caption across multiple lines?

Comment: I'm not at a computer to give a fuller response. I'm not sure if flextable allows for breaks in the caption? Can you use `as_gt() %>% gt::cols_width()`?  You can't control column widths from within gtsummary

Comment: I have the same resultas TarJae:  I get "Error in UseMethod("group_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_cross', 'tbl_summary', 'gtsummary')"" when attempting to conver tto gt.  

Interestingly enough, I'm not sure this is possible at all with Quarto output to Word -- to modify both the caption across two linse AND specify the column width.  @DanielD.Sjoberg, is this somethign that you think would be worthy of an enhancement request on your github site?

Comment: @StatStudent yes please post a reprex to the GH page if as_gt() is not working. Thank you

Comment: The first column is named 'label'. You can see all the underlying colnames with show_header_names(). There are a bunch of hidden columns , so we can reference the column by their index number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @DanielD.Sjoberg now we can do it this way. We first **must transfer the gt_summary tbl to a gt object using `as_gt()`** (and not only `gt()` -> this won't work) then we can use `cols_width()` function:

**What is also important** to select the correct column we could do:
taken from @DanielD.Sjoberg comment above:

- "first column is named `label`. You can see all the underlying colnames with `show_header_names()`. There are a bunch of hidden columns ,so we can **reference the column by their index number**.

See here https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cols_width.html

```
  
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
  tbl_cross(
    row =  Long.Petal,
    col = Species,
    percent = "cell"
  ) %>% 
  modify_caption("This is line 1  \n  This is lin 2") %>% 
  as_gt() %>% 
  cols_width(
    "label"~ px(250)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I actually like this option a lot since I can still use the statistical variables in my caption, but when I run your code I get the follwing error:

Error in UseMethod("group_vars") :
no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_cross', 'tbl_summary', 'gtsummary')"

Comment: Have you loaded `gt()`package. Are you sure using `as_gt()` and not only `gt()`?

Comment: @StatsStudent if you have group_by attribute, just `%>%ungroup %>%` before doing this

Comment: I'm not sure what deal was.  I had your example loaded exactly as is and I was getting the error.  I just restarted R and everythign works just as you have it now.  Perhaps I had some masking going on or something from a previously loaded library?  At any rate, this is a fantastic solution.  Thanks so much.  I'm going to accept this as the solution!

Comment: @TarJae.  FYI:  I also posted a revised version of my solution with flextable as well that allows the user to incorporate the summary statistics from gtsummary into the captions as well -- thank to you for making me realize that this wasn't possible from my initial set of code!  Many thanks for everyone taking the time to help me on this front!

Answer (score 3):

We may use `set_caption` from `flextable`

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    tbl_cross(
        row =  Long.Petal,
        col = Species,
        percent = "cell"
    ) %>%    
    as_flex_table() %>%
    set_caption(caption = "This is line 1 <br/>This is line 2", 
      html_escape = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm outputting my table to MS Word via quarto.  This solution doesn't seem to work, with Word output format.  Instead is simply inserts the HTML break tag into a single line of text after "this is line 1," so that the caption reads:  "This is line 1 <br/>This is line 2."  Any way to get this working with Word?

Comment: @StatsStudent Sorry, I didn't catch the Word document in your post

Comment: No problem.  Your response was actually helpful in finding a solution!  Thank you so much!  I posted my solution just now!

Comment: @StatsStudent Just saw your post with `as_paragraph`.  Great option

Answer (score 3):

After the helpful suggestions from both @akrun and @daniel-d-sjoberg, I was able to get a version of this working and output to Word in Quarto using the following code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: docx
editor: visual
#filters:
#  - docx-landscape.lua
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)
mytable <-   iris %>% 
      mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    tbl_cross(
      row =  Long.Petal,
      col = Species,
      percent = "cell"
    ) %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>%   #NEW CODE LINE 1
  width(., 1, 1) %>%         #NEW CODE LINE 2
set_caption(
   as_paragraph(
      as_chunk("caption  \n caption 2", props = fp_text_default(font.family = "Cambria"))
    ), word_stylename = "Table Caption")

mytable


```
````

This produced:

[image]

Thanks for everyone's help!

**UPDATE**

After @TarJae's answer, I realized this solution doesn't support summary statistics in the captions from the gtsummary package.  So, I've decided to slightly modify this solution and provide one that will allow the user to include these.  This can be accomplished as follows:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
#| echo: false
mytemptable<-iris %>% 
    mutate(Long.Petal = ifelse(Petal.Width > .2, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    tbl_cross(
        row =  Long.Petal,
        col = Species,
        percent = "cell"
    ) %>%    
  modify_caption("First Line of the Caption  \n Second Line with the total sample size is {N}")
  
  mytemptable %>% 
    as_flex_table() %>%
    set_caption(
   as_paragraph(
      as_chunk(mytemptable$table_styling$caption[1], props = fp_text_default(font.family = "Cambria"))
    ), word_stylename = "Table Caption")
```

All I've done here is to initially generate the label using gtsummary.  Then I convert the table to a flextable and pull in the flextable caption from the caption generated by by it (i.e., mytemptable$table_styling$caption[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb1XJ.png), in the example above).